# .NET Core Request REST MessageInspector

Tags: rest, wcf, .net-core, iclientmessageinspector

I have a backend application in .NET Core 6 that makes calls to different external services. Until now it was all SOAP calls.

I used a class that inherited from `IEndpointBehavior` and this in turn used a class of its own that inherited from `IClientMessageInspector`.

This way I could access from any place of my code to the calls that were made from my application to outside, and I had a common place to make operations with them.

Now I want to do the same but with REST calls, and I can't find the way to do it.

Apparently `IEndpointBehavior` cannot be used with REST calls.

Could you tell me how to adapt the code?

Thanks

Edit:
Here you can see an example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Something similar to this is what I have for SOAP.

So I can inspect / modify the response and request of my SOAP calls.
This piece of code is COMMON for any call I make from all my application.

The idea is to do something similar for REST calls.

Comment: How to adapt the code to do what? The question is not clear; please articulate further what you want to do with respect to REST APIs, as it isn't possible to deduce this at present.

Comment: Here you can see an example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Something similar to this is what I have for SOAP.

So I can inspect / modify the response and request of my SOAP calls.
This piece of code is COMMON for any call I make from all my application.

The idea is to do something similar for REST calls.

Comment: Explain what _exactly_ you want to do. You could be looking for an HttpMessageHandler.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for an interface or method to achieve the same effect as IClientMessageInspector for rest calls.

Comment: yes @jiayao
Exactly

Comment: You may take a look at [this article](https://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector) and see if it can help you.